# Difference between partial derivatives, differentiability and continuous differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, continuity, partial-derivative

Imagine we have some piecewise defined rational multivariable function $f: R^2 \to R$. At the origin,  $(x,y)=(0,0), \; f=0$

If I find the partial derivatives with the limit definition in the points $x,y$ I get some well defined function $f_x, f_y, for (x,y)\neq(0,0)$ right. Is that proof that the partial derivatives exist? Will $f_x, f_y$ also be equal to zero even if we divide by zero for instance? Because lets say I evaluate these in some point, I will get a value so it exists except in the origin for instance. And if I check for differentiability the limit does not equal zero in the same point that the partial derivatives exist. Now let's say the function is continuous in that point however. What can I classify the function as? Is it continuously differentiable because it is continuous and has partial derivatives that exist, or is it not because it is not differentiable in the point? What is the difference between the three.

Comment: Is f a single variable function or two- variable function? If it is single-variable, why do you give $f:R\rightarrow R^2$ and then write (x,y)=(0,0)? Is this a point, or $f(0,0)$? I made an edition to clarify that. Then you give the case of a two-variable function g(x,y). So how can f being single variable have partial derivatives? g certainly has.  What is the connection between f and g? Did you mean  $g:R^2\rightarrow R^3$? Please clarify

Comment: sorry i meant $R^2 \to R$. f is the original function and g is $f_x$ h is $f_y$ for instance.

Comment: If $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)$ then the partial derivatives exist at the origin - but it doesn't mean f and g are continuous at the origin. You can use the same principle elsewhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions See also this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188834/how-do-i-show-that-partial-derivatives-exist-everywhere

Comment: "Is it continuously differentiable because it is continuous and has partial derivatives that exist" Do you have a textbook where you can look up the definition of "continuously differentiable"? One that gives a slightly-too-general definition would be the free OpenStax Calculus Volume 3 which mentions it [here](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-3/pages/6-6-surface-integrals?query=continuously%20differentiable&target=%7B%22type%22%3A%22search%22%2C%22index%22%3A0%7D#fs-id1167794058811), but if you're using another text, it probably presents things more straightforwardly.